# How does the Improvise for Real method compare to others?

Tags: guitar, improvisation, learning-resources

What is the Improvise For Real approach to learning how to improvise and how does it compare to other methods?  I would also love to hear about experiences with learning from the resources.

One thing that's attractive to me is the way he visualizes the fretboard.  Just another way that is slightly different from others, but makes sense to me.  Perhaps it would be a good thing to explore for that reason alone.

https://improviseforreal.com/

Here's one of the youtube videos from the channel:

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the video you included, the method seems to be based on using the chord notes as the starting point of improvisation, rather than the more common, but too simplistic, approach of "use this scale on these chords". That is an excellent approach in my opinion.

You can listen to a guitar lesson on improvisation (and other things) by Pat Metheny here:

and I suggest to pay special attention to the points where Pat demonstrates the difference between improvising with only scales vs improvising with awareness of the chord notes.

You can also check the "Improvisation By Degrees" method.